# How can I store the data returned from an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

```js
async function getDetails(country){
  let response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`);
  let [data]= await response.json();
  return data
}

let portugal = getDetails('portugal');
```

Is there a way to store the data returned from a async function in JavaScript?

I know, the async function will always return a promise, and can use ".then(func)" to do another thing with the data. But how can i store it in a variable and use it later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can.

```js
let portugal = await getDetails('portugal');
```

If you don't use `await` keyword before `getDetails()` you will get the promise as you correctly pointed out and not the data result.

Note that `await getDetails()` only works when being called inside an `async` function.

Comment: You can use [.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) too
(Without await infront of course)